# MIPS - Storing ints, arranging them and then adding the ints into a sum

Tags: arrays, sorting, mips

So the assignment is to make a 'calculator' that can store 10 inputs into an array, sort them from smallest to largest value and then add them all together, but no matter how i try the output doesn't print out the numbers and the sum. I'm not sure where I went wrong so if anyone could take a look at it it would be very much appreciated.

```
        .data 
array:  .space 40               #space for array
msg1:   .asciiz "Welcome to sorting calculator!\n"
msg2:   .asciiz "Please enter 10 random numbers:\n" 
msg3:   .asciiz "Sorting your inputs...\n" 
msg4:   .asciiz "Numbers in ascending order\n"
msg5:   .asciiz "Total sum of your input:"

    .text
    .globl main
main:
    #Print string msg1 
    li  $v0,4               # print_string syscall code = 4
    la  $a0, msg1           # load the address of msg1
    syscall 

    #Print string msg2 
    li  $v0,4               # print_string syscall code = 4
    la  $a0, msg2           # load the address of msg2
    syscall     

    li  $t0, 0              #counter for i 

loop1:                      #First loop
    beq $t0, 10, sort           #end loop when equal to 10
    li  $v0, 5              #get input of integer from user 
    syscall         
    sw  $v0, array($t1)         #Store the result in array
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1         #++i
    j loop1         

sort: 
    #Print string msg3 
    li  $v0,4               # print_string syscall code = 4
    la  $a0, msg3           # load the address of msg3
    syscall

    li  $t0, 0              #counter for i 
            
loop2:                      #for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++)
    li  $t1, 1              #counter for k
    beq     $t0, 10, end_loop2      #end loop when equal to 10

loop3:                      #for(k=i+1; k<11; k++)
    beq     $t1, 11, end_loop3      #end loop when equal to 11 (10+1)
    lb  $t6, array($t0)         #load numbers[i] into t6
    lb  $t7, array($t1)         #load numbers[k] into t7
    bgt     $t6,$t7,if          #jump to if when $t6>$t7
    addi    $t1, $t1, 1         #increment k by 1
    j   loop3               #jump back to loop3

if:                     
    lb  $t2, array($t0)         #store numbers[i]
    lb  $t3, array($t1)         #store numbers[k]
    sb  $t3, array($t0)         #numbers[i] = numbers[k]
    sb  $t2, array($t1)         #numbers[k] = temp
    j   loop3               #jump back to loop3

end_loop3:
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1         #increment i by 1

end_loop2:
    #Print string msg4 
    li  $v0,4               # print_string syscall code = 4
    la  $a0, msg4           # load the address of msg4
    syscall 
    
    li $t0,0                #initialize i
loop4:
    beq $t0, 10, sec5           #end loop when equal to 10
    lb  $t5, array($t0)         #load numbers[i]
    li  $v0,1               #print_integer syscall code = 1 
    addi    $a0, $5,0       
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1         #increment t0 by 1
    j   loop4

sec5:
    #Print string msg5 
    li  $v0,4               # print_string syscall code = 4
    la  $a0, msg5           # load the address of msg5
    syscall 
    li  $t0, 0              #counter for i 
    
loopsum:                    #loop to calculate sum
    beq $t0, 10, printsum       #end loop when equal to 10
    lb  $t8, array($t0)         #load numbers[i]
    add     $s7, $s7, $t8           #sum+=numbers[i]
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1         #increment t0 by 1
    j   loopsum
    
printsum:
    li  $v0,1               # print_integer syscall code = 1 
    addi    $a0, $t4,0
    syscall 

end:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: it shows the lines of text, then gets ten inputs of integers, then it prints out the rest of the lines of text but not the arranged integers nor the sum it goes like 

"Welcome to sorting calculator!
Please enter ten random numbers: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Sorting your inputs...
Numbers in ascending order
Total sum of your input:0"

Comment: Ok, and do the numbers appear sorted in memory?

Comment: where should i look for it?

Answer (score 0):

## Basic Debugging Skills

### Static Debugging Skills

Write pseudo code in C and make sure it works.  It sounds like work but is actually a simplification — it is very hard to find algorithmic & design flaws in assembly language when you're first learning assembly.  Small design fixes in pseudo code can also result in larger change in assembly.

Translate your pseudo code into assembly with rigor.  Don't "optimize" during translation to assembly — if you want to optimize, do that in the pseudo code.  Here I'm talking about, for example, converting the algorithm from using indexing into pointers (do that translation in the pseudo code in C and make sure it works), or, changing a while loop into a repeat until.

Read the assembly code and look for flaws.  Compare register sources and targets with variable names from your pseudo code — it is surprisingly easy to have a typo.  Run parts of the code in your head.  Look for off-by-one errors; make sure loops have proper exit conditions, and maintain proper state for each iteration.  Compare with your pseudo code and make sure each piece is present and in the right place.

### Dynamic Debugging Skills

Anyone writing assembly language should be able to single step and watch/verify their code execute.

Single step and verify that each instruction does what you expect.  Most instructions have a main effect: change the value of a register, or change the value of memory.  And all instructions tell the processor what instruction to run next.  So, we need to verify the main effect and the control flow (what instruction comes next).  (syscalls can change multiple memory locations and offer a return result as well.)

When you're debugging fresh code that's never been tested, use the smallest possible input to make debugging simple.  Expect typos in your code, such as wrong register source, wrong register target, etc..

As you evolve your program, use breakpoints to skip over code that you already know is working, then single step the new code from there.

When you can, use the smallest possible input and try debugging with that first, then make it larger.  In this case, you could change your 10 to a 1 or 2 to make it easier to single-step and find the most basic bugs.

---

I found your first bug after single-stepping of less than 30 instructions from the beginning.  You should have been able to do this.

The user entered data is being stored in the first word of your array.  Since you neither initialize nor increment the index `$t1`, all the words are stored in the same place, each one overwriting the prior.  Maybe should have been `$t0`, but that would have to be scaled for word size.  So, maybe you're missing an instruction to scale `$t0` and put that value into `$t1`.

Comment: how do i initialize or increment the index $t1, and how does scaling work?

Comment: In C we do `a[i]`.  This, in C, is short for `*(a+i)`, which means: unary `*` dereference the address computed by `(a+i)`, where `a` is the array base (a pointer) and `i` is an integer variable (the index).  While C knows the size of the array elements (if integer elements, each value occupies 4 bytes) and will automatically scale `a+i`, in assembly we have to be explicit about that. C's `a+i` in assembly needs to be `a+i*4` -- this is explicit scaling (that C does for us implicitly).

Comment: is it okay to ask for an example of how the assembly would look like because I've never learned C before and I'm extremely confused